# Null Object Reference: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'booleanabi44_0_0.com.facebook.react.unimanager.FabricViewStateManager.hasStateWrapper()'

Tags: react-native, crash, expo, textinput

my code suddenly stopped working, when I navigate to a login screen the app crashes with this error.
although I tested the app yesterday before wrapping up and it worked fine, now it is not
I have narrowed down the problem and it is caused buy TextInput from react-native, when I comment all TextInput's the error disappears.
can someone help?
[image: This is the error I get]

Comment: see this thread: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17372 - here's how you can work around it for now: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17372#issuecomment-1119866941

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is sad to say that this happened to only to Expo Go users, if you're building it with bare react-native all will work fine.

the new update of Expo Go client in our phones (lol bcs emulator is too heavy for our potato laptop) which is the 2.24.1 version, where it has new UIs which looks better, is the culprit of our problem. They have a thing with TextInput component from react-native..

resolve? downgrade our Expo Go client back to 2.23.x from third party apk websites like apk2pure, hope this help!

source: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17372

Comment: I installed back the earlier version of expo go 2.23.2 and it works again, thank you